# Find an explicit formula for an integral

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem of real analysis.

Let $f(x)=|x|$ and define $F(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}f$.

(a) Find an explicit formula for F

(b) Where is F continuous? Where is F differentiable? Where $F'(x)=f(x)?$

**For (b)** Since $f(x)=x$ is integrable in $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we know that $f(x)=|x|$ is also integrable in $[a,b]$.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F$ is continuous (in $[a,b]$?) and $\forall x \in[a,b]$ where f is continuous, $F'(x)=f(x)$.

In this case, $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. So $F'(x)=f(x)$ in those places? (more especifically, intervals that don't include the $0$.

Is this correct?

What about part (a)?

Answer (score 3):

If $x \le 0$ then $F(x) = \int_{-1}^x (-t) dt = {1 \over 2} (1-x^2)$.

If $x >0$ then $F(x) = \int_{-1}^0 (-t)dt + \int_0^x t dt= F(0) + \int_0^x t dt = {1\over 2} (1+x^2)$.

Combining, we see $F(x) = {1 \over 2} (1+x|x|)$.

The above formulae show that $F$ is differentiable for $x \neq 0$ and $F'(x) = f(x) = |x|$.

Since $|F(x)-F(0) - 0\cdot x| \le |x|^2$, we see that $F$ is differentiable
at $x=0$ and $F'(0) = 0$.

Hence $F'(x) = f(x)$.